# Query on 2 properties of the same embedded object in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection of objects :

```
db.coll.find().pretty();

{
    "_id" : "1",
    "elements" : [
        { "key" : "A", "value" : 10 },
        { "key" : "B", "value" : 1 },
    ]
}, 
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "elements" : [
        { "key" : "A", "value" : 1 },
        { "key" : "C", "value" : 33 },
    ]
}
```

I want to find the documents that contain an element with "key" equal to "A" AND its "value" is greater than 5.

Not sure if this is possible without using the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without aggregation, using **[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples)** and query will be as below :

```
db.coll.find({"elements":{"$elemMatch":{"$and":[{"key":"A"},{"value":{"$gt":5}}]}}}).pretty()
```

or if you want use aggregation then used following query for aggregation

```
db.coll.aggregate({"$unwind":"$elements"},{"$match":{"$and":[{"elements.key":"A"},{"elements.value":{"$gt":5}}]}}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query

```
db.coll.find({elements: {$elemMatch: {key: "A", value: {$gt: 5}}}});
```

It uses $elemMatch operator. The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria. (Refer [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/))